# Make a div fill the remaining horizontal space of a parent div with a dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div fill the remaining horizontal space of a parent div which has an dynamic width (based on screen width).

How can I achieve this with pure CSS?
What I try to achieve is shown in the picture below ('Fillable space').

[image: Image to show what I try to achieve]

The code for the following example would currently be:

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

    #container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px 30px;

        #static-div {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
        }

        #fillable-space {
            /* What would my code be to fill the remaining space? */
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in regards

Comment: @SurajPalwe as I stated above; I'm trying to achieve this using pure CSS.

Comment: You got ans but this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359025/css-layout-dynamic-width-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use

```
width: calc( 100% - 60px );
float:left;
```

like i did in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74ovL80s/

and if you need to support legacy browsers look here to see if they support the calc function: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: I never heard of 'calc' before. This seems to work nice and it's supported by most browsers... Thank you sir.

Comment: You are very welcome - glad i could tell you something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support browsers that doesn't support [css calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) such as IE8, you can do like this.

```css
#wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
 #container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    height: 70px;
    background: grey;
}
#static-div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
#fillable-space {
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="static-div">
            
        </div>
        <div id="fillable-space">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```